# Neo4j: Can you add to the numeric value of a property?

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to increase the value of a property on a node? For example, I have a node like this:

```
(a {id:'a', value:1})
```

And if it already exists, I want to increase the value of a property. Something along the lines of this:

```
MERGE (a {id:'a'})
ON MATCH SET
a.value=+2
```

...so that `a.value` is now equal to **3**.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
MERGE (a {id:'a'})
ON MATCH SET a.value = a.value+2;
```